# Invoking plugins in declarative Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Trying to port the following syntax from scripted pipeline to declarative pipeline and it is not working.  Obviously, I am getting error message that step is not a valid keyword in declarative Jenkinsfile. Could not find any documentation to fix the issue.  Any help?

```
stage("publish to s3") {
step([
    $class: 'S3BucketPublisher',
    entries: [[
        sourceFile: 'mybinaryFile',
        bucket: 'GoBinaries',
        selectedRegion: 'eu-west-1',
        noUploadOnFailure: true,
        managedArtifacts: true,
        flatten: true,
        showDirectlyInBrowser: true,
        keepForever: true,
    ]],
    profileName: 'myprofile',
    dontWaitForConcurrentBuildCompletion: false, 
])
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This should work as long as the code is in a `script` block.  This is the standard way to run scripted pipeline code within a declarative pipeline.

```
stage("publish to s3") {
  steps {
    script {
      step([
        $class: 'S3BucketPublisher',
        entries: [[
          sourceFile: 'mybinaryFile',
          bucket: 'GoBinaries',
          selectedRegion: 'eu-west-1',
          noUploadOnFailure: true,
          managedArtifacts: true,
          flatten: true,
          showDirectlyInBrowser: true,
          keepForever: true,
        ]],
        profileName: 'myprofile',
        dontWaitForConcurrentBuildCompletion: false, 
      ])
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In declarative pipelines, `stage` should have `steps` block

```
stages{
  stage('someName'){
    steps {
      //s3bucketpublisher step
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: [Jenkins documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#stage)

> The stage directive goes in the stages section and should **contain a steps section**, an optional agent section, or other stage-specific directives.

Comment: The problem with that though, I get syntax error for $class.  E.g.,stages{
  stage('someName){
    steps {
      $class: "S3BucketPublisher"  - generates syntax error
    }
  }
}

Comment: just to confirm, I forgot quote after someName. I corrected it. Can you try now?

Comment: thanks for your help.  I added script tag with steps as you suggested above.  That worked.